# Does Quarkus have a notion of session variables/cookies?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

Thinking to how Php operates, there are both client and server 'cookies', where the server cookies are session-dependent data that is only seen by the server.

Does Quarkus have anything similar to this? I realize I could make something that would effectively produce this behavior with session client cookies, and internal data maps, but was hoping there might be something along these lines already established.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus does **not** really implement any specific session management. The rationale is that it is focused on Microservices, so the system should be as stateless as possible.

What is does have is support for CDI's `@SessionScoped` if `quarkus-undertow` is being used.

Comment: What about `@SessionScoped`? What about form based authentication? What about Qute? Would all these things make any sense without state?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Qute does not introduce any sort of sessions scope.

Comment: I can see that, Qute doesn't have to have state (in the frame of stateless servers), but yeah when making a ui it would be nice to store things away from danger (client) and therefore session data would be nice. Looking into that seems to be on the path of what I'm looking for though

Comment: You are welcome to open a Github issue asking for this feature